# Python - Match a string without whitespace except newline at the end?

Tags: python, regex

I want to test for the entry into the terminal of a single word, i.e. 'Cat' (without anything at the end).

This allows "Cat     ":

```
re.match(r'[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,15}', x)
```

This doesn't allow even 'Cat' to be entered!:

```
re.match(r'[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,15}[^\s]', x)
```

What am I doing wrong? To clarify, it asks for an input and the person has to type Cat and hit enter, no spaces at the end. Thanks! :)

Comment: You just need to add an `end-of-string` anchor i.e. `$` to your regex: `re.match(r'[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,15}$', x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `x.replace(' ', '')`. This allow even 'Cat     ' and '      Cat' (or '    Cat    ')